# SQL JOIN not returning any results

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I have a fairly simple join for three tables that is not returning any results. If I modify slightly I get sometime that appears jumbled (same data values in two fields). There is a Documents table from which I need the filename, a Variable table which has the variable definitions and names, and lastly I have a VariableValue table that the values for the variables are stored in. I am trying to get two values for each filename. Subject and Author. Here is the SQL call.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT Documents.Filename, VariableValue.ValueText AS Author,
    VariableValue.ValueText AS Subject 
    FROM Documents INNER JOIN
    VariableValue ON Documents.DocumentID = VariableValue.DocumentID INNER JOIN
    Variable AS VV1 ON VariableValue.VariableID = VV1.VariableID INNER JOIN
    Variable AS VV2 ON VariableValue.VariableID = VV2.VariableID

    WHERE (Documents.Filename LIKE N'ECO-%') AND (Documents.Deleted = 0) AND 
    (VV1.VariableName = N'Author') AND (VariableValue.ValueText <> '-') AND 
    (VV2.VariableName = N'Subject')
    ORDER BY Author asc
```

If I remove the (VV2.VariableName = N'Subject') I get the following result:

```
Filename         Author     Subject
ECO-27533.docx  billpark    billpark
ECO-27630.docx  billpark    billpark
ECO-27683.docx  billpark    billpark
ECO-27790.docx  billpark    billpark
ECO-27812.docx  billpark    billpark
ECO-27975.docx  billpark    billpark
```

If I remove the (VV1.VariableName = N'Author') I get the following result:

```
Filename        Author  Subject
ECO-28720.docx  24006   LOW PWR BM DUMP 24006 LOW PWR BM DUMP
ECO-28595.docx  24052   PIN THREAD CORRECTION   24052 PIN THREAD CORRECTION
ECO-28517.docx  24087   24087
ECO-28791.docx  25584   REV A TO B  25584 REV A TO B
ECO-28714.docx  25873   PRESSURE RELEAF ASSY    25873 PRESSURE RELEAF ASSY
```

What I would like is:

```
Filename        Author       Subject
ECO-28720.docx  billpark     LOW PWR BM DUMP
```

Not sure what subtle thing I am missing?

TIA.

DDL

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Variable](
    [VariableID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [VariableName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [VariableType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [FlagUnique] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [FlagMandatory] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [FlagFreeUpdateAllVersion] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__Variable__FlagFr__05EEBAAE]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [FlagFreeUpdateLatestVersion] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__Variable__FlagFr__06E2DEE7]  DEFAULT ((0)),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Variable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [VariableID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

AND

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VariableValue](
    [VariableID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DocumentID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProjectID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RevisionNo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ConfigurationID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ValueText] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_VariableValue_ValueText]  DEFAULT (N''),
    [ValueInt] [int] NULL,
    [ValueFloat] [float] NULL,
    [ValueDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ValueCache] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_VariableValue_ValueCache]  DEFAULT (''),
    [IsLongText] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_VariableValue_IsLongText]  DEFAULT ((0)),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_VariableValue] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [VariableID] ASC,
    [DocumentID] ASC,
    [ProjectID] ASC,
    [RevisionNo] ASC,
    [ConfigurationID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[VariableValue]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_VariableValue_DocumentConfiguration] FOREIGN KEY([ConfigurationID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DocumentConfiguration] ([ConfigurationID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[VariableValue] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_VariableValue_DocumentConfiguration]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[VariableValue]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_VariableValue_Documents] FOREIGN KEY([DocumentID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Documents] ([DocumentID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[VariableValue] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_VariableValue_Documents]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[VariableValue]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_VariableValue_Projects] FOREIGN KEY([ProjectID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Projects] ([ProjectID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[VariableValue] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_VariableValue_Projects]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[VariableValue]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_VariableValue_Variable] FOREIGN KEY([VariableID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Variable] ([VariableID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[VariableValue] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_VariableValue_Variable]
GO
```

Comment: The join criteria between variable and variablevalue is the same on both variable joins:  so in essence your query says show all variables that have a name of author and subject.  A record can't be both so no records returned.  I would need to see an DDL for variable and variablevalue to help figure it out as well as sample data from both.

Comment: In the situation where a Variablevlaue for a given document has multiple entries due to either configuration, revision or project, which value do you want returned?  the most recent? the earliest?  which? I would guess the most recent but that's not stated.

Answer (score 0):

```
VariableValue.ValueText AS Author,
    VariableValue.ValueText AS Subject
```

You're calling the exact same alias.columnname and assigning it to both Author and Subject.

Comment: True, but this doesn't explain why no records are returned; it does provide a hint/clue however.

Comment: Yes, your comment explains that part of it.

Answer (score 0):

We need to add projectID, revisionNo and ConfigurationID to the results as the PK for VariableValue is a composite key. If we don't include them, then the results could get mixed up for different projects/revsions or configurations.

So unless you have a rule that says only return the latest revision for a document... we may get multiple records back.

```
SELECT Documents.Filename
     , VariableValue.ProjectID
     , VariableValue.RevisionNo
     , VariableValue.ConfigurationID
     , max(Case when VV1.VariableName = N'Author' then VariableValue.ValueText END) as Author
     , max(Case when VV1.VariableName = N'Subject' then VariableValue.ValueText END)  AS Subject 
FROM Documents 
INNER JOIN VariableValue 
   ON Documents.DocumentID = VariableValue.DocumentID 
INNER JOIN Variable AS VV1 
   ON VariableValue.VariableID = VV1.VariableID 
WHERE (Documents.Filename LIKE N'ECO-%') 
  AND (Documents.Deleted = 0) 
  AND (VariableValue.ValueText <> '-') 
  AND (VV1.VariableName in (N'Author',N'Subject') 
GROUP BY Documents.Filename
     , VariableValue.ProjectID
     , VariableValue.RevisionNo
     , VariableValue.ConfigurationID

ORDER BY Author asc
```

Comment: Docs can only have one Author and Subject, but they do have multiple revisions.

Comment: Trying your code yields an error in syntax for the Group keyword.

Comment: Think I have it!

Comment: yeah had an extra , in the group by now removed. Still unsure if this is 100% what you're after. It might be close; but I'm still concerned about multiple records coming back for a document with multiple configurations projects or revisions.

Answer (score 0):

With a terrific assist from xQbert this code does it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Documents.Filename, max(Case when VV1.VariableName = N'Author' then VariableValue.ValueText END) as Author, 
                                    max(Case when VV1.VariableName = N'Subject' then VariableValue.ValueText END) AS Description 
FROM Documents INNER JOIN
                         VariableValue ON Documents.DocumentID = VariableValue.DocumentID INNER JOIN
                         Variable AS VV1 ON VariableValue.VariableID = VV1.VariableID INNER JOIN
                         Variable AS VV2 ON VariableValue.VariableID = VV2.VariableID
WHERE (Documents.Filename LIKE N'ECO-%') AND (Documents.Deleted = 0) AND  (VV1.VariableName in (N'Author',N'Subject') AND (VariableValue.ValueText <> '-'))
Group BY Documents.Filename
ORDER BY Author asc
```

Comment: I'd do some more testing with this.  If you have variablevalue with multiple revisions, configurations or projects with different values for the variables this will yield inconsistent results.  You really need to consider how to handle revisions/configurations/projects.  While this does work and give some results the results will be inconsistent until you consider the other elements of the composite key on Variablevalues

Comment: Let me put this a different way: without addressing the full composite key of VariableVale, you will likely have incorrect results if valuetext changes to a lesser value over a project, revision, or configuration.   So if Revision 1 has a value text of Z, and revision 2 has a value text of Y with all else being the same, Y will be returned; when you may want Z.  It's why I group by the other components of the key.  When what you likely want is the most recent revision's values.

Comment: Interesting. With the type of documents (Word) I am dealing with here in this particular case configurations and revisions are not of concern (they don't get revs and configs) however other files in the system would. In most cases wether a Word file or not we do usually want the latest version. Clearly you have a grasp on the how the system is set up. Really  very thankful for your input and insight.

Comment: awe shucks; I'm blushing!  I just wanted to make sure you understood the risks of your proposed solution.   I think it would result in incorrect values potentially and wanted to make certain you understood those risks.  The fact you say the documents are word docs and imply they don't contain changes in project,revision or configuration ease my concerns.  It's not so much a grasp on the system; it's an understanding of relational db design and PK/FK relationships; which I'm able to apply to this setup.  Good luck!