# Join and/or Sub QUERY with Composite Key Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, sql-server-2014, composite-primary-key

I asked a similar question a few days ago. I have three tables. The DDL for each table is found in this thread ([SQL JOIN not returning any results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46301060/sql-join-not-returning-any-results)).  My needs have changed slightly (this is my shocked face) and I haven't had much success in getting to what I need; close, but not quite.

What I would like to do is hand in a users name (or part of there name, i.e. LIKE) and get back the Description (Variable.Value table) and the document filename (Documents table). Of the latest revision. I have done this to get the latest rev with great success. I have tried in a myriad of ways to plug in the authors name (variablevalue table) to get exactly what I am after. I have tried a subquery with no luck either. I think the composite keys are catching me out as I have not done a lot of work with composite keys as yet. TIA.

```
Select Distinct vv.ValueCache 
from VariableValue vv, Documents d
where d.filename like 'ECO-%' and d.deleted = 0 and  d.DocumentID = vv.DocumentID and
vv.VariableID =  ( Select VariableID
                   from Variable
                   where VariableName like 'Description') and 
vv.RevisionNo = ( Select Max( Vv1.RevisionNo )
                  From VariableValue vv1 
                  where vv1.VariableID = vv.VariableID and
                        vv1.DocumentID = d.DocumentID and
                        vv1.ValueText is not null ) and
vv.ValueCache != ''
order by vv.ValueCache ASC
```

Here is the missing DDL for the Documents table.

```
USE [PDM_NT_Vault]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Documents]    Script Date: 9/29/2017 9:51:40 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Documents](
    [DocumentID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Filename] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [LockProject] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__TemporaryU__Mode__3B75D760]  DEFAULT ((2)),
    [UserID] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__Temporary__UserI__3C69FB99]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [LockDomain] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [LockPath] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Busy] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__TemporaryU__Busy__3E52440B]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [Flushed] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Documents_Flushed]  DEFAULT ((1)),
    [DefValStored] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Documents_DefValStored]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [RevGenCounter] [int] NULL,
    [LatestRevisionNo] [int] NULL,
    [CurrentStatusID] [int] NULL,
    [WorkingVersionModified] [int] NULL,
    [ExtensionID] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Documents_ExtensionID]  DEFAULT ((1)),
    [LockDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [UserDocRefsModified] [bit] NULL,
    [Deleted] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Documents_Deleted]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [Shared] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Documents_Shared]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [LockViewID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Link] [bit] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Documents_Link]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [DocTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [ObjectTypeID] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Documents_ObjectTypeID]  DEFAULT ((1)),
    [Flags] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Documents_Flags]  DEFAULT ((0)),
 CONSTRAINT [aaaaaDocuments1_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DocumentID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Documents_FK00] FOREIGN KEY([UserID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([UserID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Documents_FK00]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_DocType] FOREIGN KEY([DocTypeID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DocType] ([DocTypeID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_DocType]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_FileExtension] FOREIGN KEY([ExtensionID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[FileExtension] ([ExtensionID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_FileExtension]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_ObjectType] FOREIGN KEY([ObjectTypeID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ObjectType] ([ObjectTypeID])
NOT FOR REPLICATION 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_ObjectType]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_Projects1] FOREIGN KEY([LockProject])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Projects] ([ProjectID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_Projects1]
GO
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: 1) JOIN 2) EXISTS

Comment: You dont have  a DDL for `documents` on your other question. Also we need sample data and expected output. And not putting the ddl here is just lazy, make us go there to check for the full info to the question.